# Invisible faces

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I extracted a model from a game. Normally this works fine but this particular object seems to have invisible faces. I wanted to do UV wrapping but the selection of multiple parts of the object is not even on the image and some of them are displaying correct textures? Also, when I select these faces the correct image isn't shown even though it is in the assets.

The UV wrapping is not on images but still have the textures?

[image: overhanging UV map]

It's invisible here
[image: invisible areas]

moving the UV wrapping selection of the invisible one to brick texture does not change anything
[image: moving the UV wrapping selection]

This is how its supposed to look like.

[image: desired result]

[image]

Comment: The first image - yes, because you have Image node set Repeat. The second issue I cant reproduce. You didnt pack images with blend, but if I load some it is there.

Comment: Sorry new to blender, how i pack images with blender?

Comment: you have 6 different materials, if you move UV it doesn't change the material

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html

Comment: I cant seem to upload the blender file as its 80 mb and only 30mb allowed hmm. but if i move UV its supposed to get the metrial shape atleast no?